# NextJS - conditionally pull data from an external API with getServerSideProps

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I need to pull data from an external third-party API, and the request to the API has to come from the server-side rather than the client-side (the API will reject client-side requests).

I'm looking to use [`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props), since according to the NextJS API it *" only runs on server-side and never runs on the browser"* which is exactly what I need.

However, once I pull the data from the API, I won't need to re-pull the data for another 15-30 minutes. During that time, I would use the previous response.

For this, [`swr`](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/getting-started) sounds good, since it can be made into a [reusable hook](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/getting-started#make-it-reusable) and *"there will be only 1 request sent to the API, because they use the same SWR key and the request is deduped, cached and shared automatically."*

The page's flow would look like:

1. User navigates to page and requests data
2. If the data does not already exist from a prior pull, use `getServerSideProps` to pull and store the data
3. If the data does exist and was pulled within the last 30 minutes, use `swr` (or some other method) to call an internal API and process the existing data, thereby avoiding another external API request.

The problem with this is `getServerSideProps` "*must be exported as a standalone function — it will not work if you add getServerSideProps as a property of the page component*", and it will run every time the page is requested.

Is there a way I can use `getServerSideProps` but only run it conditionally? Or is there another way that is more appropriate for this situation?

Comment: Check out ISR - set the `revalidate`  time to 30min - https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration.  Next also has on-demand revalidation to have a trigger instead of a lapsed time.  You can create a static page with your server data, and if you need to run client-side queries, you still can while leaving the server data cached.

Answer (score 0):

use `getStaticProps` which only runs during build-time. HTML will be created and will be placed into cache. when first request comes, html will be served from the cache

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
 
  const data = await fetchData(args);

  return {
    props: {
     // make sure you do not return undefined. it does not get serialized
      myProp: data,
    },
    // first request will be returned from cache
    // then data will be revalidated and cache will be updated
    revalidate: 10*60, // In seconds. 10 minutes
  };
}
```